# Type checking object property in Record in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the code, you can see that the `valueof` gives `string | boolean | Location` - so I can mismatch the types and it still works! I want to type-check the particular object property with its related type.

PS: New to TypeScript here. Appreciate anyone who would redefine the question/ put it in better words.

```
type valueof<T> = T[keyof T]

enum Events {
  LOG = 'Log'
}

enum Properties {
  API = 'Api',
  CONNECTED = 'Connected',
  LOCATION = 'Location'
}

export enum Location {
  PROFILE = 'Profile'
}

interface EventParam {
  [Properties.API]: string
  [Properties.CONNECTED]: boolean
  [Properties.LOCATION]: Location
}

interface AnalyticsEvent {
  action: Events
  params: Partial<Record<keyof EventParam, valueof<EventParam>>>
}

const AnalyticsEvents: Record<string, AnalyticsEvent> = {
  LOG_API: {
    action: Events.LOG,
    params: {
      [Properties.API]: true,
      [Properties.CONNECTED]: Location.PROFILE,
      [Properties.LOCATION]: 'This should fail'
    }
  }
}

export default AnalyticsEvents
```

Answer (score 2):

When we look at the `Record` type, we see that you use `keyof EventParam` as possible keys and `valueof<EventParams>` as possible values. But there is no  association here between specific keys and values, so any combination is valid.

Use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) instead:

```
interface AnalyticsEvent {
  action: Events
  params: {
    [K in keyof EventParam]?: EventParam[K]
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAbghgGwK4QPYDMA8AVAfFAXimwG0BrCEDYgXQFgAoRiAOyQFsoBRGV4AZygBvRlCgAZAPIBxQlADk41AHN5jAL6NmbTgAUATqkj7gASwiCRDMQEFdASTnybYU-IA0oqAGFJAOT8ub2wuABEnb1QWFggAY2AIABMPLylvG2x7fyclWLgzKLUGTSYGCAAPMFQTKFYOCVQ8gpZhL10AJUkAMXtxLicDDFMECCKSxlMWBP10OFjoHj5dOH04TisxEkHjMwsAOjt7GgAuKH5gfUnlLy3DHfN%20Pd8AoJDQk6gAI1RUEbgWG7bCAmB57NIZLJ%20D65fKmKIaLQMSbTWbzKA2FiIEBmWL8RZTVrWKBzZqnfECLxgFZrfinDZiKAkADSUEmUAoVHQ3F4U2Wq3YNAA-GSecA%20WtmfQiSVxgxYlFzujMQhsaZceTaVB2nFqolMOdLixlO4lVicXjRfgiPSpNIAPqHOleMQkuEsEV8R62zxEsRU-ma%20kMxlAkH7Q4fABEFxQkZ9wc2od2j2egWCYWhjVhUT2HW6vS48YTtyMwOTYMk6Uy-g%20swQ-AgzqgJTEMqAA)